# How to print what a bash script is actually running?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script which will:

1. Add all changes to git
2. Commit with a message I pass to the bash script
3. Push it to the repo

I am trying to do this with:

```
m=\"$*\"
git add -A
echo git commit -m $m
git push
```

However, I am getting errors saying `error: pathspec 'Q2,' did not match any file(s) known to git.` for everything word I pass to the script.

How can I see what bash it actually doing? When I put `echo` in front of the offending line (which I presume is the commit) I get a correctly form command. If I put it in to the terminal, I runs find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see what bash is doing, add `-xv` options to the shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```

The problem is probably the quoting. `m=\"$*\"` does not do what you want. `$m` is still split into several words if it contains whitespace, just the first word starts with a doublequote and the last word ends in a doublequote.

Rather, change the offending line to

```
git commit -m "$m"
```